# How to set View of Layout

Tags: java, android

How can I set view of layout with using `LayoutInflater`. It means i need take view on Layout and set this on other layout

something like this

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(this.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_strona_glowna,null);
LinearLayout  a = findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
```

i want to set `layoutInflater` on view of `'a'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using addView() method.

```
a.addView(v);
```

Comment: I tried this and  occurs an error "Cannot resolve symbol 'addView' "

Comment: Read this link for your new error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690640/cannot-resolve-method-addviewandroid-widget-textview

Answer (score 1):

'findViewById' returns a view, please convert it to a `LinearLayout`.

```
LinearLayout  a = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);
a.addView(v);
```